# How to fix the deformation when moving a robotic arm?

Tags: rigging, blender-internal-render-engine, bones, weight-painting

[image]

How can I fix the deformation, I tried to change the weight but it didn’t work

Comment: Could you upload your blend file? Would help us, help you =) Use this http://www.pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: First impression though, is that you have two or more bones influencing that part of the robotic arm. Could be any one of the other bones. Loop through them all and check the weight painting

Comment: did not work i tried it

Comment: If you upload your blend-file, I can take a look =)

Comment: In your image you have the lowest bone selected, when you want to have the red part attached to the next bone up.

Comment: i tried every thing but still didn’t work

Comment: i uploaded the blender file